Property of Metric Space That Allows Closed Sets to be Written as Intervals of Arbitrarily Small Length
I was recently working on proving a theorem about specific types of porous sets in $\mathbb{R}$ that relied on the fact that in $\mathbb{R}$, given any $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $N\geq 1$, we can rewrite the closed interval $[-N,N]$ as a union of intervals each of length $\frac{1}{N}$, namely $[-N,N]=[-N,-N+\frac{1}{N}]\cup...\cup[N-\frac{1}{N},N]$. I was wondering how this property of being able to decompose a set into sets of arbitrarily small lengths could generalize to certain metric spaces? i.e. given a general metric space $(X,\rho)$, what conditions on the space do we need to guarantee that the closure of a basic open (where we are only interested in non-degenerate closed and bounded sets) can be split up in such a way? Any advice or knowledge would be greatly appreciated!

FYI, in the mid 1990s I proved several results (unpublished, mainly because heavy teaching loads in the late 1990s gave me no time) in which the assumption $\sigma$-totally bounded was useful. I don't know to what extent $\sigma$-totally bounded is actually used anywhere (totally bounded, of course, is a very well known notion) -- I basically made it up in analogy with $\sigma$-compact but figured it's too un-quirky to not be a real thing -- but it was a useful assumption for several results similar to Note 6 in this conference "abstract".

It seems to me that the most direct analogy would be to write a set $E \subset X$ as a (finite) union of, say, balls of radius $\varepsilon > 0$ fixed (arbitrarily small). But this relies rather on compactness than closedness.
Conversely, compactness is enough since you can extract a finite covering from $(B(x, \varepsilon))_{x \in E}$. You can then get the equality back (instead of just an inclusion) by intersecting each of these balls with $E$.
